# Knowing the defect (mitigating false positives)

Tags: qa-role, test-strategy, skillset

During testing, there are areas you need to be sure are covered before you are sure you found a bug:

- technology (are you sure you are understanding the technology behind the AUT - how stuff works)
- tools (are you using the tools the right way, is everything set up correctly)
- business logic (are you sure you understand what is the app supposed to do)
- testing skills (maybe your testing skills are up to the challenge)
- individual factors (are you focused, well-fed and rested and such)

What are the strategies to mitigate false positives? Or, how to be sure you found a bug?

Comment: You are getting a lot of false positives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strategy would be the similar to when you have real defects. False positives and defects happen due to a cause, those can cover a very very broad scope and differ a lot per issue.

1. Analyse the cause. Do a simple personal [root-cause analysis](https://www.jamesshore.com/Agile-Book/root_cause_analysis.html).
2. Apply [Systems Thinking](https://less.works/less/principles/systems-thinking). Draw it out, find feedback loops.
3. Define mitigation measures. E.g. create a checklist item to prevent it from happening again, update documentation or take a fundamentals course.

Comment: Good stuff to read. Also, checklist is a great idea.

Comment: Yeah, checklists are nice, aslong you mark the last date something happend and remove items after a couple of weeks/months. Your behaviour improves/changes. So checklist items should not be gates for ever :)